# professionals or professional's

Tags: grammatical-number

I received feedback that it is 'medical professional's" rather than "medical professionals" in the following context:

> Using our solution you can remove the stress of data security from
>   medical professionals.

I think the reviewer is confused and I am right.  I think the reviewer is thinking in terms of a singular noun possessive apostrophe s

Example:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/apostrophe

> The dog’s tail wagged rapidly.

But professional is a noun and the plural is professionals.

Can anyone confirm if I am correct?

Comment: It depends on the context.  You need to show us more.

Comment: @Xanne I inserted the sentence however, the context is as said previously, the plural of professional.

Comment: Yeah, the reviewer is simply wrong.

Comment: If that's the whole sentence, then professionals is a plural and you're right.

Comment: Just ask the reviewer, "medical professional's WHAT?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence "Using our solution you can remove the stress of data security from medical professionals" is grammatically correct. The only way to use PROFESSIONAL'S with the apostrophe in this sentence would be to restructure it as "you can use our solution to remove the medical professional's stress of data security." PLEASE NOTE: There are a few other possible complicated constructions, such as "you can use our solution to remove the hospital's stress of data security, and also the medical professional's"  but your own construction is clearer, and by far the simplest.